# Is it possible to trigger a webforms validator from JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have to do a JavaScript submit on another form on the same page as a regular ASP.NET form (with validators) and it needs to trigger one of my `RegularExpressionValidators`. Can you trigger one via js?

Answer (score 0):

You can just simulate a button click with jQuery and this will trigger the Validators.

So when you have your basic form with a Button and a Validator

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"
     ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="myGroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="myGroup" />
```

And then the fake button click to trigger the Validators. If you do not want the original button to be visible just hide it with CSS.

```
<input type="button" onclick="simulateClick()" value="Simulate Click" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function simulateClick() {
        $("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").click();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This would work but it'd trigger all of the validation when I only need it on one field.